# Webflow - transition not triggered in view-state

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, cas, spring-webflow-2, jasig

I try to add some functionalities to Jasig CAS, so I have to add

**lost_login-webflow.xml :**

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
    <var name="lostLoginModel" class="***.*****.LostLoginModel" />

    <view-state id="viewLostLoginForm" view="casLostLoginView"
        model="lostLoginModel">
        <binder>
            <binding property="email" />
        </binder>
        <on-entry>
            <set name="viewScope.commandName" value="'lostLoginModel'" />
        </on-entry>
        <transition on="submit" to="lostLoginSubmit" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="lostLoginSubmit">
        <evaluate
            expression="lostLoginAction.submit(flowRequestContext, flowScope.lostLoginModel, messageContext)" />
        <transition on="success" to="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />
        <transition on="error" to="viewServiceErrorView" />
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="viewGenericLoginSuccess" view="casLoginGenericSuccessView" />
    <end-state id="viewServiceErrorView" view="viewServiceErrorView" />
</flow>
```

In my jsp, I set `<input type="hidden" name="execution" value="${flowExecutionKey}" />` and `<input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />`.

My view is well load in the url */lostLogin* but nothing happen when I submit my form... (my form is based on the default form from CAS server)

Even if I replace `<transition on="submit" to="lostLoginSubmit" />` with `<transition on="submit" to="viewGenericLoginSuccess" />` nothing happen

So why I never go in my transition ?

Comment: When you say "nothing happends" what is the HTTP response code you are getting back from the server?

Comment: The status of the request is 200

Comment: I bet an exception is getting swallowed somewhere. Turn debug logging for package path org.springframework.webflow and see if you can spot it.

Comment: How do I do that ? I added `<logger name="org.springframework.webflow"><level value="DEBUG" /></logger>` in log4j.xml but I have nothing more in the console

Comment: Make sure you have a 'console' <appender> defined and registered to the <root> tag. Also change "DEBUG" to "debug"

Comment: and the log4j.xml needs to be in src/main/resources folder

Comment: <root> tag ? this is my appender : `<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%c] - &lt;%m&gt;%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>`

Comment: so add the following as the last tag
 <!-- Root Logger -->
 <root>
  <priority value="info" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
        </root>

Comment: I have something similar, see my entire file here : http://pastebin.com/2xbwAeEV

Comment: do you see any logs from any package in the console? If no make sure the log4j.xml is in src/main/resources otherwise spring framework won't pick it up. Also change "DEBUG" to "INFO" and see if that displays some output. The configuration file looks correct so either it is in the wrong path and not being automatically picked up by spring framework or some other type of user error (example: like editing the wrong log4j.xml file)

Comment: and in that file you are already suppose to be displaying all org.springframework projects' DEBUG output. So if you're not seeing a constant stream of output then that is an indicator the log4j.xml file was NOT detected.

Comment: the file log4j.xml is in the right directory and the only logs I can see when I load pages in my server are http://pastebin.com/PURxEryT

Comment: in the server deployment, I have : Class Path entry lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar in "/C:/Dev/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/cas-server.war"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference. is that the problem ?

Comment: That is a deployment issue but you should be running this in an embedded web server in your IDE first to reduce the number of variables which should detect all the jars automatically. So the logging is working you're just not seeing anything for webflow. What happends if you remove the "<logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>" from the file? or changing the level to "DEBUG" for

Comment: Find the log4j.xml on the deployment path on your server and inspect the contents of the file. Make sure it is the same as in your IDE

Comment: Ok, you found the issue, I can't find the file in the deployment folder... but I don't know why, the file is in my Eclipse project

Comment: Probably an issue with the deployment infrastructure you are using but that is really a separate issue you can manually copy log4j.xml or whatever jars that are missing then worry about why it is not automated later.

Comment: I did add manually log4j.xml file in `cas-server.war\WEB-INF\classes` but nothing more happened. It's maybe because I deleted log4jconfiguration.xml file from my project ? (there was a conflict with the server JBoss (it initialize log4j already))

Comment: http://pastebin.com/X2nUUs3m : It say that log4j.xml is not in "classes" directory, but it is ! ...

Comment: not familiar enough with jboss to comment but it is pretty standard to export the log4j.xml from src/main/resources and place it in that 'WEB-INF\classes' path when creating a war file. Though I really think this is a separate deployment issue and not related to SWF. Why can't you run this application inside an embedded jboss server in eclipse or whatever IDE you are using?

Comment: and when I said to manually do it I meant AFTER THE WAR HAS BEEN UNPACKED to overwrite the log4j.xml on the deployment path with the one with the SWF logger entry

Comment: and this is really just a hack to get you going. It shouldn't make things more complicated

Comment: My JBoss server is linked with my Eclipse. I think it's what you call "embedded". (however, I didn't do the installation, I'm just in an internship) But there is no log4j.xml on the deployment path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a real answer but I updated my CAS server from 4.0.3 to 4.1.0-RC1, and the transition was invoked... (I didn't change anything in my web flow config)